# MySQL query that looks for substring in column?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm using this query to look for User results. The problem is that it only finds exact matches. How do I make it check for string as substring in column User?

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE MATCH (`User`) AGAINST ('$string') LIMIT 5");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `User` LIKE '%$string%' LIMIT 5");
```

Use the [**`LIKE`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html#operator_like) operator, that's what it's there for.

Also, I hope you are escaping the `$string` variable earlier in the code with [**`mysql_real_escape_string`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) to protect against [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Answer (score 1):

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `User`LIKE '%".$string."%' LIMIT 5");
```

Comment: String concatenation is costly.

Answer (score 1):

Change your query to use the `LIKE` keyword and the `%` thingy-mabobber:

```
SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `User` LIKE '%$string%' LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM pet WHERE name LIKE '%fy';
```

You can read more [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the LIKE operator.

Something along the lines of:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `User` LIKE '%$string%' LIMIT 5");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp